# best powerpoint presenter for linux

Tags: linux-mint, reference

I am using Linux Mint 17.1 rebecca.

I need to use a powerpoint presenter in my laptop. Are such Powerpoint presenters are OS dependent? If so what can I use on my Linux?

I am using Beamer class to prepare the presentations, which makes it as a pdf file.

And in this view, I need to present my presentation with the presenter... For that only i am searching a good [Power point presenter](http://www.amazon.in/Wireless-Remote-Control-Presenter-Powerpoint/dp/B00SZ31RKQ/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1424262802&sr=1-2&keywords=powerpoint%20presenter)  which is compatible to linux...(see the linK)

Help me to do this...

Comment: what do you mean powerpoint presenter? a tool? a powerpoint like software ?

Comment: Libre Office Impress is official software to linux. I use LaTeX Beamer free tool for power-point presentation.Still now i never faced any difficulties on this tool.

Comment: Powerpoint is a brand name, for a presentation software from Microsoft. Are you looking for equivalent software? What do you mean by best? Does it have to be compatible? Or are you after something that makes it easy to create slides? Or that makes it easy to present? Or that produces nice slides? Small files? … All these are available, but you need to be more clear about what you are looking for.

Comment: If you use the Beamer LaTeX class, you don't need another presentation software. Just use your pdf viewer in "fullscreen" or "presentation mode".

Comment: I think i am not clear in my question @Leiaz I am asking about the hardware which helps us to present like this product http://www.amazon.in/Wireless-Remote-Control-Presenter-Powerpoint/dp/B00SZ31RKQ/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1424262802&sr=1-2&keywords=powerpoint+presenter

Comment: This specific model says in the description "no need to install drivers" and "pad and buttons that work like a mouse", so there is a big chance that it'll behave like a standard HID mouse. Shopping questions are still off-topic though. If you google "remote laser pointer linux" or "presentation remote linux", you'll see many models just work like a standard mouse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Libre Office Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) (or [Open Office Impress](http://www.openoffice.org/product/impress.html)), which are very powerpoint alike.

If you want a pointer then go for any USB, all of them are recognized out of the box in Linux (as a mouse).

Comment: Also install `libreoffice-presenter-console` it makes presentation easier (when using 2 displays: laptop and projector), it will show presentation on projector, and a control console on laptop display.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at  [FreeOffice Presentations](http://www.freeoffice.com/en/features-freeoffice-presentations), which is a free version (somewhat restricted) of a commercial product. In my experience their compatibility with Office documents is much higher than LibreOffice or OpenOffice.